# Automatically starting a child process with 'High' priority?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, process, plugins, priority

My computer running Windows 7 is getting old, and Flash content stutters a bit too much. I am finding that elevating the priority of the plugin process helps a lot.

I know of the `/high` switch to start an executable with 'High' priority, but I don't know how to raise the priority of a child process (plugin executable kicked off by a (parent) browser process) automatically.

I'd like to do this without installing any additional software on the machine. If there's a way to do this from the browser itself (I use Firefox and Chrome), it'd be even better.

Also, FMI: Are there any possible unintended consequences that I may be overlooking?

Comment: i found a way to start chrome browser high-priority, without need for 3rd party software. But child processes aren't always high-- sometimes low or normal. https://superuser.com/questions/1428516/how-to-make-all-chrome-threads-run-high-cpu-priority

Comment: I found a partial solution, posted at my link above.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I play a Flash video in Firefox a couple of instances of **FlashPlayerPlugin_11_7_700_224.exe** start up (version number will obviously change over time). You can run the following command to [set the priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of a process from the command line:

```
wmic process where name="FlashPlayerPlugin_11_7_700_224.exe" setpriority 32768
```

However, doing this when you start Firefox will not work since the FlashPlayerPlugin process is started on-demand, and killed once it is no longer required. So you can create a batch file that you can run as and when required, or perhaps schedule the file to be executed every say 10 mins. or so.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools outside which can adjust the priority to what you want.

One of them is [Prio](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio/). Here you can save the priority in taskmgr:

[image]

Each time you run the Program now, it will be started with the saved priority.

Comment: You have to keep Prio running for this, right? Looks like they just automated the polling of the task list and setting priority when the specified task is detected.

Comment: this is a small DLL which is loaded during Windows boot.

Answer (score 2):

Open your Firefox shortcut icon properties, and paste `%comspec% /c start /HIGH FireFox.exe` into the *Target Location* box.

Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>

That is all.

This particular shortcut will now always start Firefox at a HIGH priority,
and you can make other icons for NORMAL priority, if you want, too.