# How to make All Chrome Threads Run High CPU Priority?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, cpu, priority

Run normally, all Chrome processes have normal priority. The various threads represent various tabs, extensions, etc.

[image]

But, then i launch chrome with high CPU priority. 
I'm using:

```
cmd.exe /c start "" /high "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Then a few threads run with high priority, some Normal, and others run Low priority.

[image]

Why?

Is it possible to make all chrome sub-threads run with High priority?

Maybe i could achieve it by running chrome in single-process mode, but that's non-ideal.

Windows 10

Chrome 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial solution. By my testing, it appears to prevent any chrome process going to "low" priority, although it doesn't prevent "Normal" priority.

Use the  `--disable-renderer-backgrounding` chrome startup switch. 
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-renderer-backgrounding

`start "" /High "chrome.exe" --disable-renderer-backgrounding`

i noticed immediate improvement in Chrome performance with this switch. I believe it allows inactive tabs to load with normal priority, instead of getting low priority. I have not noticed any negative impact on the active tab.

[image]